Type hints for subset of class
I'm writing functions that act on pandas.Series with a DatetimeIndex. I can do type hints, like so:
import pandas as pd

def filter_year(s: pd.Series, year: int) -> pd.Series:
    keep = s.index.year == year
    return s[keep]

This works fine, but the editor complains Cannot access attribute "year" for class "Index". The reason is, that the editor expects any Index.
Is there a way to specify that s has a DatetimeIndex (which is a subclass of Index)?

I don't think type hinting is going to help you here. You need to check isinstanc(s.index, DatetimeIndex) in your function somewhere before you use s.index

Thanks for your comment. I'd prefer not to do that, though, as I'd litter my code with these checks. I'd prefer to let pandas throw an error if a wrong index type is used, and somehow specify a custom type of Series (one that has an .index attribute of the type DatetimeIndex).

You can explicitly do a cast to denote the type checker that s.index is of DatetimeIndex type and it does not introduce any runtime overhead.
import pandas as pd
from typing import cast
from pandas import DatetimeIndex

def filter_year(s: pd.Series, year: int) -> pd.Series:
    s.index = cast(DatetimeIndex, s.index)
    keep = s.index.year == year
    return s[keep]


Ah, I didn't know this existed - thanks! I must say it's not as readable as I'd like...There is no way to create a type, e.g. TimeSeries, which is a Series with a DatetimeIndex?

You could create a protocol class that will define what you exactly need from the passed argument. Since you are acessing the index and later indexing the series which internally calls the magic __getitem__ method, you can create the following protocol class. Admittedly, this is a bit of an overkill and I wouldn't recommend this, but it might be useful for your use.
from typing import Protocol

import pandas as pd

class DateTimeIndexable(Protocol):
    index: pd.DatetimeIndex
    
     def __getitem__(self, *args) -> pd.Series:
        ...

Your adapted code would then look like:
import pandas as pd

def filter_year(s: DateTimeIndexable, year: int) -> pd.Series:
    keep = s.index.year == year
    return s[keep]

And your IDE should properly recognize all used types.

Thanks for your answer! This works in this case, but there will also be code that relies on s being a Series. And not just any object with an index attribute of the type pandas.DatetimeIndex, which is what your solution causes, is that correct?

In that case using pandera could be appropriate? It's a package made for validating and let's say type hinting pandas objects. SeriesSchema might be useful https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/generated/pandera.api.pandas.array.SeriesSchema.html#pandera.api.pandas.array.SeriesSchema

For SeriesSchema you can set the index parameter where you can set it's datatype.  Last time I used it the integration with editors wasn't that good so this might be a dead end

I've tinkered around with it and am now wondering if there is a reason the following shouldn't be used?
import pandas as pd

class TimeSeries(pd.Series):
    index: pd.DatetimeIndex

def filter_year(s: TimeSeries, year: int) -> TimeSeries:
    keep = s.index.year == year
    return s[keep]

...and if there is a way to silence the new warning: "index" incorrectly overwrites property of the same name in class "Series"
The only issue I see with the code is that, to the user, it might be unclear that a TimeSeries cannot be initialised. I'm not sure if there is a way to prevent this.

Your solution seems fine. Try putting  # type: ignore after index: pd.DatetimeIndex to silence the warning

I think this would cause issues in the editor in code calling this function since the editor will (rightfully) complain when you pass a pd.Series object to the function.

If there were a way to "AND" types, that would be easiest. Like: s : pd.Series && DatetimeIndexable (with DatetimeIndexable as a protocol, with only the .index property).

I think you can do
import pandas as pd

def filter_year(s: pd.Series, year: int) -> pd.Series:
    index: pd.DatetimeIndex = s.index
    keep = (index.year == year)
    return s[keep]

